# No space after Section label in overleaf

Tags: spacing, sectioning, cross-referencing

No space after the Section label:

You can see the output is:

```
    \documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{ICCAS2021}
    
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{xurl}
    \usepackage{diagbox}
    
    
    \begin{document}
        
    This paper is structured as follows. 
        Section~\ref{section 2} describes the proposed method, Section~\ref{section 3} presents experimental results and discussion, and Section~\ref{section 4} concludes this work and future work.


\section{Methodology}
\label{section 2}

\section{Results and Discussion}
\label{section 3}
\section{Conclusion}\label{section 4}
    
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is not the expected output so it is due to code you have not shown. Please always post code as a complete small document that produces the output shown. We can not debug a fragment.

Comment: David Carlisle, I edited it.

Comment: I get `! LaTeX Error: File \`ICCAS2021.cls' not found.` can you reproduce this with a standard class such as `article` (if not, it is a bug in that class and you should report it to the maintainers of that file)

Comment: Is ICCAS2021.cls from http://2021.iccas.org/?page_id=964? It seems to contain some unsuitable definitions: `\def\thesection{\arabic{section}. \hskip -1em}` (and also for `\thesubsection`, `thesubsubsection`). This should indeed be reported to the maintainer.

Comment: @imnothere good grief :(  Redhwan searching for iccas I ended up at last year's http://www.ieee-icca.org/submission.html  which has a link to ieeconf.cls which does work, you could maybe use that until the organisers fix this class.

Comment: Thanks all for your help and explanation.